# What does input buffer mean in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I know there is a `DBCC INPUTBUFFER` command in SQL Server, which

> [Displays the last statement sent from a client to an instance of SQL Server.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-inputbuffer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

To me it seems that input buffer IS the SQL a session is running.

SQL Server also has `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`, which

> [Returns the text of the SQL batch that is identified by the specified sql_handle.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sql-text-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

And `sys.dm_exec_input_buffer`, which

> [Returns information about statements submitted to an instance of SQL Server.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-input-buffer-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

I'm kind of confused. They seems very similar and unidentifiable to me.

I also come across [an article](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/understanding-the-sql_text-action-in-extended-events/) `Understanding the sql_text Action in Extended Events` by Jonathan Kehayias. In the article, he states

> With this event session created, we can then run a couple of different test scenarios in the environment to show how this action is not the sql_text, but is instead the input_buffer for the event that is being fired

He's very confident that SQL text is not input buffer, which I don't understand the reason. Could anyone help clarify a little bit please? Thanks.

Comment: Execute a stored procedure and compare what the different methods show you

Comment: I tried. Both `DBCC INPUTBUFFER and `sys.dm_exec_input_buffer` show ``EXEC dbo.usp_LongRunningTask`. The `sys.dm_exec_sql_text` shows `CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_LongRunningTask AS...`. So the input buffer is the executing statement, and sql text is the `create procedure` statement that defines the procedure?

Comment: With the sql text  you can use the statement offset to get the exact statement in that proc definition that is currently executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `DBCC INPUTBUFFER`
  Displays the command actually sent by the client under the specified session (and particular request). This may be an ad-hoc batch, or a procedure.
- `sys.dm_exec_input_buffer`
  Is the newer form of the above, which allows the resultset to be used as part of another query.
- `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`
  Gives the SQL text for a particular batch or plan handle.
  You can get this handle in a number of ways, but often you will get one for the *currently* executing command of a session via `sys.dm_exec_requests`, which may be nested down the call stack from the original request, such as via a procedure, function or trigger.  Because this may be part of a larger SQL batch, you need to use `statement_start_offset` and `statement_end_offset` to parse out the exact text of the command being executed.
- *the `sql_text` Action in Extended Events* is a particular issue with XEvents, that the action (data field) called `sql_text` actually represents the input buffer, not the currently executing command, ie the theoretical result of `sys.dm_exec_input_buffer` not of `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`.